# Some elements lag in jQuery accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the link to the accordion menu: [jQuery accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/td5VC/1/)

The issue i am having is to open and close the Menu 1 item smoothly, but the On/Off buttons give an impression as if it was lagging.

I think that this is caused by the following css, but cannot see any improvements that could be done:

```
.md_toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 3px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.md_toggle input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 0;
}

.md_toggle p {
    position: absolute;     
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.md_toggle p span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.md_toggle p span:last-child {
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.md_toggle .md_slide-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
    width: 51%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: provide a link which reproduce your issue. CSS is not usually what makes a animation lagging but still could. BTW, why not trying to debug it on your side? Remove all CSS relevant rules and see what happen by reappend it one by one, and so on...

Comment: A link is provided in the beginning of the question, it is the following: http://jsfiddle.net/td5VC/1/

I have tried removing css rules, but did not succeed in solving the issue.

Comment: Oh sorry but the title you use for link let supposed it is a link for jquery accordion plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with lagging you mean that the On/Off items are not revealed but show instantly, it happens because they are absolutely positioned.

Add a css rule

```
.accordionContent{
    position:relative;
}
```

so that the contents are hidden while the revealing is in progress..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/td5VC/4/

**update** removed the `overflow:hidden` as it was not needed..